# Can't preview Rails App on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm unable to open my Rails App in Heroku despite being able to git push to heroku? I have setup Heroku in the past and have successfully been able to view the apps but with this one I'm drawing a blank. To be honest I don't even know which files to begin looking in.

Can anyone here please help me nut this out! I'm working on Nitrous and can preview the app locally no problem.

heroku logs -t yields:

```
action@chrome-comet-112003:~/workspace/hootandholla_lp(master)$ heroku logs -t
2015-08-05T10:11:46.113755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163410+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-05 10:11:47] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163413+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163416+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163418+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163420+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163422+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163423+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163424+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163419+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163428+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163426+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163427+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163429+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.182568+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-05 10:11:47] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-08-05T10:11:47.182661+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-05 10:11:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163431+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.163432+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-08-05T10:11:47.193884+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-08-05T10:11:50.101489+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-08-06T05:34:27.497781+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c279b16 by justindavidson23@gmail.com
2015-08-06T05:34:27.497781+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by justindavidson23@gmail.com
2015-08-06T05:34:27.545639+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-06T05:34:27.545647+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-06T12:07:05.149371+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-06T12:07:05.149391+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-06T12:07:05.078014+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9ee6257 by justindavidson23@gmail.com
2015-08-07T04:02:54.198603+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-07T04:02:54.198619+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-07T04:03:29.349940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2015-08-07T04:03:29.349940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2015-08-07T04:03:33.183373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45764 -e production`
2015-08-07T04:03:37.162005+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:03:37] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-08-07T04:03:37.162033+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:03:37] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-08-07T04:03:37.162392+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:03:37] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=45764
2015-08-07T04:03:37.623532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-07T04:03:38.563290+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=91a31355-2162-4455-9c04-d66194cc2504 fwd="1
44.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=128ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-08-07T04:03:38.442318+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-08-07T04:03:38.442326+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:45764
2015-08-07T04:03:38.442328+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-08-07T04:03:38.442330+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2015-08-07T04:03:38.442331+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-08-07T04:03:38.442332+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 144.139.5.98 at 2015-08-07 04:03:38 +0000
2015-08-07T04:03:38.535955+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560955+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560953+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"contacts"'::regclass
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560959+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560948+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "contacts" does not exist
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560961+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560964+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560962+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560969+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560966+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"contacts"'::regclass
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560967+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2015-08-07T04:03:38.560971+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T04:03:38.561210+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562421+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562424+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "contacts" does not exist
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562425+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"contacts"'::regclass
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562427+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562429+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562431+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562433+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562435+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562436+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"contacts"'::regclass
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562438+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562440+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562441+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562443+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:3:in `new'
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562444+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562446+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T04:03:39.019675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=6ba0f50b-9218-4594-bd58-f4ced57f
4e97 fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=12ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-08-07T04:36:39.135021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2015-08-07T04:36:39.135851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-08-07T04:36:41.892417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685718+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:36:42] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685725+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685729+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685730+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685732+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685733+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685735+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685736+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685738+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685740+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685741+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685743+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685744+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685746+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685747+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685854+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:36:42] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685950+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685901+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:36:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-08-07T04:36:43.741848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

---

Thanks @Pavan
Heroku url now shows the main page(which is a form), but when i enter fields and submit, the funcionality isn't there and I get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error.

Any ideas??

heroku open yields this:

action@chrome-comet-112003:~/workspace/hootandholla_lp(master)$ heroku open
Opening nameless-taiga-1654... failed
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
    Error:       Unable to find a browser command. If this is unexpected, Please rerun with environment variable LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true or the '-d' commandline option and fil
e a bug at https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/new (Launchy::CommandNotFoundError)
    Command:     heroku open
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.40.9 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.1.1
    Error ID:    64b88457d8a247f88a34963a2479eda6
    More information in /home/action/.heroku/error.log

---

@Pavan,

action@chrome-comet-112003:~/workspace/hootandholla_lp(master)$ heroku run rake db:migrate --app hootandholla_lp
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... failed
 !    App not found

---

BELOW ARE THE LOGS AFTER RECEIVING THE FORM SUBMIT ERROR IN HEROKU

```
action@chrome-comet-112003:~/workspace/hootandholla_lp(master)$ heroku logs -t
2015-08-07T04:03:38.562446+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T04:03:39.019675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=6ba0f50b-9218-4594-bd58-f4ced57f
4e97 fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=12ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-08-07T04:36:39.135021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2015-08-07T04:36:39.135851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-08-07T04:36:41.892417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685718+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:36:42] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685725+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685729+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685730+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685732+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685733+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685735+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685736+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685738+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685740+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685741+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685743+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685744+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685746+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685747+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685854+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:36:42] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685950+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-08-07T04:36:42.685901+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 04:36:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-08-07T04:36:43.741848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-08-07T05:35:06.842966+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by justindavidson23@gmail.com
2015-08-07T05:35:10.628754+00:00 heroku[run.6076]: Awaiting client
2015-08-07T05:35:10.667373+00:00 heroku[run.6076]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-08-07T05:35:10.962380+00:00 heroku[run.6076]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-07T05:35:17.611000+00:00 heroku[run.6076]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-07T05:35:17.600075+00:00 heroku[run.6076]: Process exited with status 0
2015-08-07T05:36:43.702464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2015-08-07T05:36:43.702915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2015-08-07T05:36:47.917903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 6811 -e production`
2015-08-07T05:36:51.251009+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 05:36:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-08-07T05:36:51.251033+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 05:36:51] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-08-07T05:36:51.251363+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-08-07 05:36:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=6811
2015-08-07T05:36:51.654362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-07T05:36:52.899661+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-08-07T05:36:52.899665+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:6811
2015-08-07T05:36:52.899670+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2015-08-07T05:36:52.899667+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-08-07T05:36:52.899671+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-08-07T05:36:52.977383+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2015-08-07T05:36:52.899673+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 144.139.5.98 at 2015-08-07 05:36:52 +0000
2015-08-07T05:36:53.020950+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 22.2ms | ActiveRecord: 8.9ms)
2015-08-07T05:36:53.038490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=6111d154-4b9b-4dac-a140-1ade62597af9 fwd="1
44.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=140ms status=200 bytes=2812
2015-08-07T05:36:53.019264+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (18.7ms)
2015-08-07T05:36:53.435723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6dd87b44a2480dd4709ceeeae52df052.css" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com
 request_id=e464d2b6-3e3d-40e1-bbcf-eb19006842af fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=53ms status=200 bytes=125751
2015-08-07T05:36:53.661747+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-4f80d6744f4d98bda40010745bd45a63.js" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com
request_id=bf96090c-00c0-4247-9c3c-90de0c482f1e fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=153448
2015-08-07T05:36:55.242136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=772646ba-4f40-495b-ba01-bb91c7ac
8dfa fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-08-07T05:37:05.507033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=1be432fc-1c7f-4eea-bffa-1a69b3d697
07 fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=51ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-08-07T05:37:05.460567+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2015-08-07T05:37:05.460629+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z2Qh/GDIycId0uJk2evhblbKisGXNlIzjtz+xfJoyac=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"asdfas
d", "phone"=>"asdf", "email"=>"asdf@gmail.com", "event_type"=>"asdf", "comments"=>"asdf"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2015-08-07T05:37:05.483852+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.6ms)
2015-08-07T05:37:05.498972+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:37:05.498974+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2015-08-07T05:37:05.498976+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:8:in `contact_email'
2015-08-07T05:37:05.498978+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
2015-08-07T05:37:05.498977+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/contact.rb:7:in `send_email'
2015-08-07T05:37:05.498980+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:37:05.498981+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:37:05.457898+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/contacts" for 144.139.5.98 at 2015-08-07 05:37:05 +0000
2015-08-07T05:37:05.495367+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:37:05.497483+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms
2015-08-07T05:37:05.495371+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to justindavidson23@gmail.com (9.4ms)
2015-08-07T05:43:51.796064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=8344cbe5-537e-4d8a-9bff-9422d8fe8c
76 fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-08-07T05:43:51.770989+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2015-08-07T05:43:51.771040+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z2Qh/GDIycId0uJk2evhblbKisGXNlIzjtz+xfJoyac=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"asdfas
d", "phone"=>"asdf", "email"=>"asdf@gmail.com", "event_type"=>"asdf", "comments"=>"asdf"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2015-08-07T05:43:51.781070+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.1ms)
2015-08-07T05:43:51.792253+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2015-08-07T05:43:51.792251+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:43:51.792255+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:8:in `contact_email'
2015-08-07T05:43:51.792256+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/contact.rb:7:in `send_email'
2015-08-07T05:43:51.768324+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/contacts" for 144.139.5.98 at 2015-08-07 05:43:51 +0000
2015-08-07T05:43:51.792257+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
2015-08-07T05:43:51.792260+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:43:51.789451+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:43:51.792259+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:43:51.789454+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to justindavidson23@gmail.com (6.8ms)
2015-08-07T05:43:51.790784+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms
2015-08-07T05:43:52.221875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=cac3997f-3e24-41b7-90e8-fe8c6d11
c405 fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-08-07T05:43:57.576134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=1c19bab7-a927-408c-a603-19bb73684a2a fwd="1
44.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=738
2015-08-07T05:43:57.563828+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 144.139.5.98 at 2015-08-07 05:43:57 +0000
2015-08-07T05:43:57.566209+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2015-08-07T05:43:57.571393+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
2015-08-07T05:43:57.572163+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-08-07T05:44:05.714357+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=nameless-taiga-1654.herokuapp.com request_id=78ab7efb-59c5-40cc-b304-367f2e8a9b
ff fwd="144.139.5.98" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-08-07T05:44:05.686472+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/contacts" for 144.139.5.98 at 2015-08-07 05:44:05 +0000
2015-08-07T05:44:05.706925+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:44:05.706928+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to justindavidson23@gmail.com (6.8ms)
2015-08-07T05:44:05.708208+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms
2015-08-07T05:44:05.688638+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2015-08-07T05:44:05.688704+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z2Qh/GDIycId0uJk2evhblbKisGXNlIzjtz+xfJoyac=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"sasdf"
, "phone"=>"asdf", "email"=>"asd@gmail.com", "event_type"=>"adsf", "comments"=>"asdf"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2015-08-07T05:44:05.698623+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.1ms)
2015-08-07T05:44:05.709746+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:44:05.709748+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2015-08-07T05:44:05.709749+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:8:in `contact_email'
2015-08-07T05:44:05.709751+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/contact.rb:7:in `send_email'
2015-08-07T05:44:05.709752+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
2015-08-07T05:44:05.709753+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-07T05:44:05.709755+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

---

app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb

```
 class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default to: 'justindavidson23@gmail.com'


      def contact_email(contact)
       @contact = contact

        mail(from: @contact.email, subject: 'Contact Form Message').deliver
      end
    end
```

---

app/models/contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :email, presence: true
  after_create :send_email

  private
  def send_email
    ContactMailer.contact_email(self).deliver
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question here..but what is the best way of doing that? I've never had to before sorry

Comment: Try running `heroku logs -t`

Comment: Thanks @Pavan, have attached logs now

Answer (score 2):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation
>   "contacts" does not exist

Try running the below command

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for spending your time on this, I've updated my question above with the results of the commands you suggested

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN Did you check the logs after submitting the form?

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN can you post the codes for `app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb`, `app/models/contact.rb` in the question please?

Comment: @Pavan.have included files now. Thanks again for looking :)

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN Sorry. Its something to do with mailer settings.

Comment: Oh bummer..as in external to the app and a Nitrous setup thing?..or not sure. Sorry, thanks for trying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85378/discussion-between-pavan-and-runpixelrun).

Comment: Hi @Pavan, that'd be great!..I'm just at work at the moment though which is annoying. I'll try and get in touch with you in a couple of hours..if you're busy though no problem. Thanks again for trying, I appreciate you spending your time on this

Comment: @Pavan.I'm on chat now if it suits you..this is driving me crazy! I'm happy to give you the login details if it would make life easier for you